# preg_replace, str_replace and substr_replace not working in special condition

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I have the following code:
this code finds all html tags in a string and replaces them with [[0]], [[1]] ,[[2]] and so on.(at least that is intented but not workinng);

```
$str = "some text <a href='/review/'>review</a> here <a class='abc' href='/about/'>link2</a> hahaha";
preg_match_all("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U",$str, $out, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

$count = 0;


foreach($out[0] as $result) {

$temp=preg_quote($result[0],'/');

$temp ="/".$temp."/";
preg_replace($temp, "[[".$count."]]", $str,1);


$count++;   
}
var_dump($str);
```

This code finds all the tags in a string and replaces them with [[0]], [[1]] and [[2]] and so on. I have used `preg_match_all` with PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE.
The output of `preg_match_all` is as expected. However, `preg_replace`, `substr_replace`, and `str_replace` do not work when substituting the tags with `[[$count]]`.
I have tried all three string replacement methods and none of them work. Please point me in the right direction.
Can something in php.ini cause this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_replace` does not substitute `$str`. Assign it to the string again:

```
$str = preg_replace($temp, "[[".$count."]]", $str);
```

Also, I'm not sure what you want exactly, but this I changed some things in the [code](http://viper-7.com/w19dS9), which seems to be what you were tying to do. I changed the regex a bit, especially the `(.*?)` part to `([^<>]+)`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be in this line

```
foreach($out[0] as $result) {
```

change it to this

```
foreach($out as $result) {
```

because i think you are accessing an index that doesn't exists